# sksparse.cholmod - AssertionError

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am getting an AssertionError when trying to factorise a large sparse matrix in CSC format with cholmod.

Here is a simplified example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_array
from sksparse.cholmod import cholesky

row = np.array([0, 1])
col = np.array([0, 1])
val = np.array([1., 1.])


A = coo_array((val, (row, col)), shape=(2, 2)).tocsc()

factor = cholesky(A)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
/tmp/ipykernel_59957/2822312894.py:12: CholmodTypeConversionWarning: converting matrix of class csc_array to CSC format
  factor = cholesky(A)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 12
      7 val = np.array([1., 1.])
     10 A = coo_array((val, (row, col)), shape=(2, 2)).tocsc()
---> 12 factor = cholesky(A)

File sksparse/cholmod.pyx:1189, in sksparse.cholmod.cholesky()

File sksparse/cholmod.pyx:1216, in sksparse.cholmod._cholesky()

File sksparse/cholmod.pyx:1126, in sksparse.cholmod._analyze()

File sksparse/cholmod.pyx:411, in sksparse.cholmod._check_for_csc()

AssertionError:
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

By the way, doing it as follows works ok:

```
import scipy.sparse as scsp
factor = cholesky(scsp.csc_matrix(np.array([[ 1., 0.],
       [0.,  1.]]), dtype=np.float64))
```

but this is inefficient for my very large sparse matrix.

Comment: Interestingly, using ... A = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(coo_array((val, (row, col)), shape=(2, 2))) ... does work

Comment: I can't reproduce this with sksparse `0.4.12` and scipy `1.8.0`

Comment: It must be an issue with my jupyter configuration, because indeed in pycharm it works well.

Comment: PS: in both environments I use scikit-sparse version 0.4.12 and scipy 1.11.2